How do I create a unique index on multiple JSONB fields in Prisma?
I can create a unique index on a Postgresql Json column with this:
@@unique([car])
But, I need to create a unique index based on the year, model and color:
@@unique([car->>'year', car->>'model', car->>'color'])
I instead get:
Error: Prisma schema validation - (get-config wasm)
Error code: P1012
error: Error validating: This line is not a valid field or attribute definition.
  -->  schema.prisma:25

EDIT: If I try indexing just one field I also get the same error
